# How to generate a list of numbers from a list of numeric and alphanumeric string ranges?

Tags: python, list

Given a list

```
n = ['4276-4279', 'I69-I71', 'V104-V112', '11528']
```

From the list above, I want to match the string with hyphens and increase the numeric or alphanumeric value to a given range. So far I could only match the value using `re`:

```
p = re.compile('([\d]|[A-Z\d]{1,})[\-]')
```

Expected output:

```
['4276', '4277', '4278', '4279', 'I69', 'I70', 'I71', 'V104', 'V105', 'V106', 'V107', 'V108', 'V109', 'V110', 'V111', 'V112', '11528']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process each element in your list, seeing if it matches the pattern

```
^([A-Z]*)(\d+)-\1(\d+)$
```

i.e. an optional letter, some digits, a hyphen (`-`), the letter repeated if it was present and finally some more digits.

If it does, you can generate a `range` from the 2nd and 3rd groups, and prepend the first group to each value generated from that range:

```
import re

lst = ['4276-4279', 'I69-I71', 'V104-V112', '11528']
new = []
for l in lst:
    m = re.match(r'^([A-Z]*)(\d+)-\1(\d+)$', l)
    if m:
        new += [m.group(1) + str(i) for i in range(int(m.group(2)), int(m.group(3))+1)]
    else:
        new += [l]

print(new)
```

Output:

```
['4276', '4277', '4278', '4279', 'I69', 'I70', 'I71', 'V104', 'V105', 'V106', 'V107', 'V108', 'V109', 'V110', 'V111', 'V112', '11528']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
n = ['4276-4279', 'I69-I71', 'V104-V112', '11528']
big_list=[]
for item in n:
    print(item)
    if '-' in item:
        part1,part2=item.split("-")

        if part1.isnumeric() and part2.isnumeric():
            big_list.extend([x for x in range(int(part1),int(part2))])
            continue
        if part1.isalnum() and part2.isalnum():
            list1=re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+", part1)
            list2=re.findall(r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+", part2)
            print(list1,list2)
            temp_list=[]
            for i in range(int(list1[1]),int(list2[1])):
                temp_list.append(list1[0]+str(i))
            big_list.extend(temp_list)
    else:
        if item.isnumeric():
            big_list.append(int(item))
        else:
            big_list.extend(item)

print(big_list)
```

This code worked for me for your input.
Please try and tell me if it works.